# separate a repeated substring and characters from a string

Tags: java, string

I have strings like ihshsahasasahasiiasiia and aassiashasaaaahasssaahasii. I want to separate substring from first has to last has.

Output should be like this for to strings.
first string ouput hasasahas
second string output hasaaaahasssaahas

Shall I use substring function or pattern matching function?

Answer (score 1):

```
"ihshsahasasahasiiasiia".split("has");
"aassiashasaaaahasssaahasii".split("has");
```

Returns:

```
["ihshsa", "asa", "iiasiia"]
["aassias", "aaaa", "ssaa", "ii"]
```

respectively.

Comment: thanks I have edited my question can you please give me suggestion now?

Comment: Wait so you want to find first occurrence of has, last occurrence of has, and everything in between?

Comment: yes i want everything in between first occurrence of has and last occurrence of has

Comment: Try `myString.substring(myString.indexOf("has"), myString.lastIndexOf("has") + 3)` Beware that this will fail in a lot of cases (such as when the string has only one "has")